# React/TypeScript: Property 'actorsList' does not exist on type 'MoviePoster'. TS2339

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx

I am trying to create a list of actors (rendering li tags in react basically) for a movie poster card in react, however I am getting the error message as described in the title (full message down below) and am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**The interface:**

```
  export interface MoviePoster {
  title: string;
  posterUrl: string;
  videoUrl: string;
  description: string;
  actorsList: string[];
}
```

**The posterCard component:**

```
const PosterCard = (props: PosterCardProps) => {
const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);
  const { posterUrl, title, description, actorsList } = props.moviePoster;
  const actors = actorsList.map((actor) => <li key={actor}>{actor}</li>);
return (
    <>
      <div style={styles.container} onMouseEnter={() => setIsHover(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setIsHover(false)}>
          <ul>{actors}</ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <MovieSnippetPopUp moviePoster={props.moviePoster} isHovered={isHover} />
    </>
  );
};
```

**The homepage where I am using the PosterCard component:**

```
const HomePage = (props: HomePageProps): JSX.Element => {
  const { theme } = props;

  const styles: Styles = {
    container: {
      background: theme.BACKGROUND,
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
    },
  };

  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <Header theme={theme} />
      <PosterGrid
        moviePosters={[
          {
            posterUrl: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61rv%2BRnsu6L._AC_.jpg',
            title: 'Avenger',
            videoUrl: '',
            description: 'Avenger',
            actorsList: ['Thor', 'Bob', 'Joe'],
          },
        ]}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**PosterGrid:**

```
interface PosterGridProps {
  moviePosters: MoviePoster[]; //Creating an array of MoviePoster objects
}

const PosterGrid = (props: PosterGridProps): JSX.Element => {
  const { moviePosters } = props;

  const styles: Styles = {
    container: {
      display: 'block',
      height: 'fit-content',
      width: 'fit-content',
      padding: 'auto 0',
    },
    topPosterCardsContainer: {
      display: 'flex',
      height: 'fit-content',
      width: 'fit-content',
    },
    bottomPosterCardsContainer: {
      display: 'flex',
      height: 'fit-content',
      width: 'fit-content',
    },
  };

  const moviePosterCardsTop = moviePosters.map((value) => <PosterCard moviePoster={value} />).slice(0, 3);
  const moviePosterCardsBottom = moviePosters.map((value) => <PosterCard moviePoster={value} />).slice(3);

  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <div style={styles.topPosterCardsContainer}>{moviePosterCardsTop}</div>
      <div style={styles.bottomPosterCardsContainer}>{moviePosterCardsBottom}</div>
    </div>
  );
```

**Error Message1:**

```
Property 'actorsList' does not exist on type 'MoviePoster'.  TS2339

    13 | const PosterCard = (props: PosterCardProps) => {
    14 |   const [isHover, setIsHover] = useState(false);
  > 15 |   const { posterUrl, title, description, actorsList } = props.moviePoster;
       |                                          ^
    16 |   const actors = actorsList.map((actor) => <li>{actor}</li>);
    17 | 
    18 |   const styles: Styles = {
```

**Error Message2:**

```
index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
```

Essentially, in order to create some list tags in react, I created a list of strings that will hold all the names of the actors in the MoviePoster interface, and then render each element in that list within a list tag.

Comment: It could be a stupid answer but just to be sure: did you saved all the edited files? Because the error it seems related to the interface and as I can see from your snippets it's correct

Comment: @Danielo yes I have saved multiple times just to be sure

Comment: so maybe ts is not correctly transpiling. Did you tried to stop the tsc watcher and  then restarting?

Comment: @Danielo I doubt its anything wrong with ts transpiling. I used inspect element and found another error: index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. I will update the question

Comment: oh, lol i didn't noticed: you are trying to accessing to a prop but this is an array:


```
[
          {
            posterUrl: 'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61rv%2BRnsu6L._AC_.jpg',
            title: 'Avenger',
            videoUrl: '',
            description: 'Avenger',
            actorsList: ['Thor', 'Bob', 'Joe'],
          },
        ]
```

Comment: @Danielo so how do I use it properly in the ul tag? Can you please show me an example?

Comment: About the warning:

you have to add a key to each element you are iterating:

```
actorsList.map((actor) => <li key="<some-id>">{actor}</li>);
```

At the place of some-id you should use some unique key of each actor (wich could be a id for instance)

Comment: that's could be an example: https://gist.github.com/irsooti/15d998aa4cc817391bd4f5343388af64

Comment: @Danielo I've tried the same thing as you've implemented above, but I'm still getting the same errors

Comment: @DreamVision2017 please add `PosterGrid` component to the question

Comment: @Anthony Just updated

Comment: You have to do the same thing in moviePosterCardsTop and moviePosterCardsBottom